# Converting HTML to PDF Invoice

Tags: c#, html, css, .net-core

I'm trying to generate HTML page ( C# Razor View ) that will be converted to PDF ( using wkhtmltopdf )and printed on pre-printed stationery.

My problems is, that the pre-printed stationery has a header ( easy ) 
and tear-off part at the bottom (4cm) which should be blank until the very last page where some additional information is printed.

The whole invoice is being generated as

```
<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>
```

So how can I set margin of X on every page except the last printed
and on that last printed page instead of margin actually print something?

Tried to use  with last-child selector but that did not work.

Perhaps some other solution will be more suitable for this using .Net Core ( some linux apps can be used as well )?

Comment: Have you tried the `:last-of-type` Selector?

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp

Comment: Just tried (         tfoot:last-of-type { background-color: aqua;  }. Each tfoot on a printed page has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got to the bottom of that. 
As the top of the page should not be a problem ( can be handled the same way as well , but the table thead is another option )

My solution is:

```
 wkhtmltopdf test.html --footer-html footer.html output.pdf
```

And the whole trick is withing the footer.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var mainHeader = "test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>";
        var secondHeader = "OOOOOOOOOOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPPOPO<br>";

        function selectHeader() {
            var vars = {};
            var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
            for (var i in x) {
                var z = x[i].split('=', 2);
                vars[z[0]] = decodeURIComponent(z[1]);
            }

            if (vars["page"] == vars['topage']) {
                document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = secondHeader;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = mainHeader;
            }

            if (vars["page"] == vars['frompage']) {
                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = secondHeader;
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="selectHeader()">

    <div style="min-height: 6cm; background-color: aqua; max-height: 6cm; overflow:visible;">
        <div id="main" onload="selectHeader()">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

ps. 
Read somewhere that without !DOCTYPE html it might not work.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `@page` rule to specify the page margins. You can also use this to specify additional margins for left & right-hand pages (to account for binding) and for the first page but not, it would seem, for the last page!

```
/* Default left & right is 2cm, top & bottom margin is 4cm */
@page { margin: 4cm 2cm } 

/* First page, 10 cm margin on top */
@page :first {
  margin-top: 10cm;
}

/* Left pages, a wider margin on the left */
@page :left {
  margin-left: 3cm;
  margin-right: 2cm;
}

/* Right pages, a wider margin on the right */
@page :right {
  margin-left: 2cm;
  margin-right: 3cm;
}
```

Further reading: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-box